# Proving a certain complex valued function is constant.

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose you have a differentiable $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ such that $f(z)\neq 0$ for any $z$.

My question is, if $\lim_{z\to\infty}f(z)$ exists and is nonzero, why does that imply that $f$ is actually constant? Thanks for any explanation.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_%28complex_analysis%29

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because $f$ is nonzero and $\lim_{z\to\infty}f(z)$, you get that $\frac{1}{f(z)}$ is entire and bounded.

The reason why $\frac{1}{f(z)}$ is bounded is simple: $\lim_{z \to \infty} \frac{1}{f(z)}$ exists and is finite. Hence, there exists an $M$ and some $R>0$ so that

$$|\frac{1}{f(z)}| < M \forall |z|>R \,.$$

By continuity $\frac{1}{f(z)}$ is also bounded on the compact set $|z| \leq R$.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have $f$ differentiable then his real part and imaginary part are Harmonic ($\Delta f=0$ or $f_{xx}+f_{yy}=0$, and all Harmonic defined on $\mathbb{R}$ bounded functions are  constants!

Answer (score 1):

You have an entire function. [Liouville's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_%28complex_analysis%29) says that bounded entire functions are constant. [Maximum modulus theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_modulus_principle) says that the maximum cannot occur properly in the domain, so must occur at $\infty$. And same for the minimum. So $f$ is bounded.